# Generating random numbers in PHP with existing code

Tags: php, random, numbers

I'm using the following code and am getting 6 random characters.  How can I increase the number of characters to 10 (or any other number)? What in this code makes it 6 characters?

```
function createRandomID() {

$chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789?";

$i = 0;

$pass = "";

while ($i <= 5) {

$num = rand() % 33;

$tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);

$pass = $pass . $tmp;

$i++;

}
return $pass;
}
```

Comment: `while ($i < 9)` gives your 10 characters. For any int `N` interval `0..N` gives `N + 1` values.

Comment: $i is 0, there is a 5 in there, 0 to 5 is six numbers ...

Answer (score 1):

You already got the right answers so your code become:

```
function createRandomID() {

$chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789?";

$i = 0;

$pass = "";

$upTo = 9 // if you want 10 or whatever - 1

while ($i <= $upTo) {

$num = rand() % 33;

$tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1);

$pass = $pass . $tmp;

$i++;

}
return $pass;
}
```